# Implementation of a deep search to solve games with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this code but it is implemented with a breadth search algorithm, as I could implement it being a depth search algorithm.
What I want to achieve is that having an initial matrix of 3x3 [4, 1, 2; 7, 5, 3; 0, 8, 6] is to get to the next array [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 0]
Using depth first search since the code below is wide.

```
%matlab
    
        I= [4, 1, 2; 7, 5, 3; 0, 8, 6]
    
     
    G=
     [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 0] 
    
    F={}; 
    Fparent = {};
    
    P=I;  
    i=1;
    
    
    S(i,:,:) = P(:,:);
    Sparent(i) = 0;
    
    
    while not(isequal(P,G))
    
     
        [x,y] = find(P==0);
        
    
        if(x > 1) 
            C = P;
            C(x,y) = P(x-1,y);
            C(x-1,y) = 0;
            F{end+1} = C;
            Fparent{end+1} = i; 
        end
    
        if(x < 3) 
            C = P;
            C(x,y) = P(x+1,y);
            C(x+1,y) = 0;
            F{end+1} = C;
            Fparent{end+1} = i; 
        end
    
        if(y > 1) 
            C = P;
            C(x,y) = P(x,y-1);
            C(x,y-1) = 0;
            F{end+1} = C;
            Fparent{end+1} = i; 
        end
    
        if(y < 3) 
            C = P;
            C(x,y) = P(x,y+1);
            C(x,y+1) = 0;
            F{end+1} = C;
            Fparent{end+1} = i; 
        end
    
        P=F{1}; %BFS
        i = i+1;
        S(i,:,:) = P(:,:); 
        Sparent(i) = Fparent{1};
    
        F = F(2:end);
        Fparent = Fparent(2:end);
    end
    
    P(:,:) = S(i,:,:); 
    idp = Sparent(i);
    path = {P}; 
    
    while not(isequal(P,I))
        idp = Sparent(idp);
        P(:,:) = S(idp,:,:);
        path{end+1} = P;
    end
    path = flip(path);
    path{:}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is a little hard to answer. It is a little hard to understand what is the problem you are trying to solve. You have a lot of code with very little explanation of what it is supposed to archive and how it works. I would suggest you reduce your code to an easily implementable problem with clearly defined inputs and outputs. Also drawing the graph you are searching on and explaining how you represent it in your code would go a long way.

Comment: A bit of research on your side might also help narrow the problem. I think DFsearch is a widely explained algorithm and there are some great simple explanations out there: https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-dfs

Also matlab does have its own implementation of DFsearch: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.dfsearch.html#buofmjw-1_sep_shared-G

Could that help you?